# js file not loaded but next script executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple page with static JS lib references.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>some title here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//SOMESERVER.com/1.0.4815/css/public.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//SOMESERVER.com/1.0.4815/css/publicIE8.css" />
            <script src="//SOMESERVER.com/1.0.4614/js/json2.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.qbaka || (function(a,c){a.__qbaka_eh=a.onerror;a.__qbaka_reports=[];a.onerror=function(){a.__qbaka_reports.push(arguments);if(a.__qbaka_eh)try{a.__qbaka_eh.apply(a,arguments)}catch(b){}};a.onerror.qbaka=1;a.qbaka={report:function(){a.__qbaka_reports...
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//SOMESERVER.com/1.0.4815/js/knockout.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//SOMESERVER.com/1.0.4815/js/colorbox.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//SOMESERVER.com/1.0.4815/js/public.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var user = {};
            user.loggedIn = false;
            user.displayName = '';
            user.dateFormat = '';
            user.timeFormat = '';
            // bit more very simple code here
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //correct code here
            });
        </script>
```

Code works perefectly for me and for QA team. But since I use QBAKA for logging JS errors - I got around 50 errors (different browsers, IPs, timezones, datetimes) that tells me:

```
Unknown variable or function '$'
```

in line with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

I always thought that libraries executes in order of appearance, so if I include reference to jQuery, I am sure that I can access immediately - without any try-catch or other stuff.

How it is possible? jQuery library (from google server) is not available and this JS lib is not loaded and code executes further? Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing closing in document-ready handler `)`, Is this a typo?

Comment: Your code contained ignored closing braces, parentheses, etc. A point to note is you should let us know the actual paths of the libraries you are importing. `//SOMESERVER.COM/1.0.48` will rarely work on our machines. For me, a preceding // in addressbar will assume file:// protocol.

Comment: missing ')' is a typo. in real code it is present and works fine in 99.9% cases.

Comment: //SOMESERVER is my CDN server. libs refenreces by it doesn't count here, as jQuery lib is missing in some cases only.

Answer (score 1):

if you using some other custom plugin in your page so  it may be conflicts with $ (i.e Jquery)

try **$.noConflict()**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

links :

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: While this is a good idea, the error is showing that it was never made at all, so it's not a likely source of the issue.

Comment: PS - he is loading Knockout AND jQuery - both of which use $ so he still needs this code lol

Comment: there is no conflict because in 99,9% cases it works fine. only from time to time it seems like jQuery lib is not loaded. is it possible that googleapis.com failed to provied jQuery lib and next scripts on my page are executed even if previous script was not loaded?

Comment: @deryck i thought he is using some "public.js" (i considered this as third party) so it may be conflict with jquery

Comment: public.js is my own JS packed together into one minified file.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //correct code here
            });
        </script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //correct code here
            }
        </script>
```

you have not call your `$(document).ready` function properly.

Comment: missing ')' was a type. it has nothing to do with the error. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

That error can caused by :

Your `jquery` file is not being properly loaded into your page.
 or

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            )};
        </script>
```

is executing earlier than `jquery` file is loaded.

For example try this

```
<script src="https://c15123524.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and check.

Check by view source if the `jquery` is loading properly or not .

Try to download the `jquery` file and use it from your local server.

Comment: but in 99,9% cases jQuery is loaded properly. Do you mean that if jQuery lib is not loaded from googleapis.com - next script(s) is/are executed normally?

Comment: so - tell my why '$(document).ready(function () {' is executed earlier than jQuery is loaded? how is it possible?

Comment: Yes most of the cases the `jQuery` loads properly from `googleapis.com` , infect  if you check `jquery.com` they are also loading the same from `googleapis.com` . So this should work. But in your case the file may not be loading properly so I suggest to check from view source. Or you can try loading the file from local server. Like the `<script src>` I have provided.

Comment: Yes it is very much possible  `$(document).ready(function () {` is executing before `jquery` source file is fully loaded. Try loading from local server.

Comment: Dibyendu - I can't check it locally, because I got this error via qbaka (external js logging lib) - which means it happend for some users, not for me :) ... I just don't know how to prevent this error.